# Importing rospy in pycharm accompanied by a red underline

Tags: pycharm, ros, python-3.8, rospy

When I import `rospy` in `Pycharm`, `rospy` is marked with a red underline, i.e.,

[this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQE2b.png).

However, this does not affect the running of the program, i.e., I can still communicate with the ROS nodes.

It does not seem to be a serious problem, but it bothers me a lot.

I have checked the Python interpreter in Settings and the related packages have been installed.

Besides, I have finished the ROS environment setup in `zshrc` and started Pycharm in the terminal with the `sh` command.

Has anyone else met the same issue? Thanks in advance!

```
Ros version: Noetic

Python version: py3.8 in /usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the convenience of those who are experiencing the same problem, I'll give my solution here.

I have `touch` a `.pth` file in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages`, where `/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages` was added.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).